# Couldnt call controller method , ajax call with spring mvc

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem,

using spring mvc , i wanted to use ajax call , tried to call controller method but i couldnt, there is a jsp page and controller class

My Jsp page,

```
            <form role="form" >

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Ders">Ders</label>
                    <form:select path="derslist" class="form-control" id="ddlders">
                        <form:options items="${derslerlistesi}" itemValue="dersid"
                            itemLabel="ders" />
                    </form:select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="KonuAd">Konu Ad</label> <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" id="KonuAd" placeholder="Konu İsmi Giriniz!">


                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnekle" class="btn btn-default">Ekle</button>
                </div>
```

and my controller class

```
package publisher.controller;


import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import publisher.dao.Dao;
import publisher.entity.Dersler;
import publisher.entity.Konular;



@Controller
public class IslemlerController  {

    @Autowired
    private Dao dao;

    @Autowired
    private Konular _konu;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/islemler", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Home(Model model,Dersler dersler)  { 

     model.addAttribute("derslist",dersler);
     return "islemler"; 

    } 


    @ModelAttribute("derslerlistesi")
    public List<Dersler> getdersler ()
    {
        return dao.getAll(Dersler.class);
    }

    @ModelAttribute("konulistesi")
    public List<Konular> getKonular ()
    {
        return dao.getAll(Konular.class);
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/konukaydet",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    private  Konular KonuKaydet (@RequestParam String konu,@RequestParam int dersid)
    {
        _konu.setKonu(konu);
        _konu.setDersid(dersid);
        _konu.setSinavid(1);
        _konu =  dao.save(_konu);
            System.out.println("kaydet e girdi !");
        return _konu;
    }

}
```

and my script codes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnekle").click(function() {
    var input = {
      "konu": $("#KonuAd").val(),
      "dersid": $("#ddlders").val()
    };
    var inputStr = JSON.stringify(input);
    alert(inputStr);
    $.ajax({
      url: "/islemler/konukaydet",
      type: "POST",
      data: inputStr,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(output) { // callback method for further manipulations
        var str = JSON.stringify(output);
        alert("success ");
        $("#output").text(data);
      },
      error: function(data) { // if error occured
          alert("err");
        $("#error").text(data);
      }
    });

  });
});
```

thanks for help!

Comment: Can you inspect response of you call on browser and check what response code is it returning?

Comment: Good, then close this question by accepting or voting the comments

Comment: actually i got a new problem ajax call success not firing on my codes below, it work it call the method and do some work but dont firing success ajax call have you got any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem in script, you need to pass data as query parameter because you have used `@RequestParam` in controller class. so in your ajax call your url should like below.

```
url: "/islemler/konukaydet?konu="+input.konu+"&dersid="+input.dersid;
```

**Note** - you didn't use `islemler` **URL** in your controller. `@RequestMapping(value="/islemler/konukaydet",method=RequestMethod.POST)`

It may help you, if not please reply me.

If you want to use your script as it is, then you need to change in your controller and use `@RequestBody` and use a model

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Sam's point, according to your url on js, you need to add @RequestMapping at **controller** level. So your controller should look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/islemler")
    @Controller public class IslemlerController {
```

So by combining request mapping at *controller* level and  *KonuKaydet* method level, you now would have complete desired request mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have configured the controller in **dispatcher-servlet.xml**

If not [see this](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorials/spring-framework-jquery-ajax-request-and-json-response-example)

If you are running it in local machine then you need to invoke the call as

`$.ajax({ 
   //other options. .
   url: http://localhost:<port>/<your-url>
   //other options. .
});`.

Moreover `@RequestMapping` should be given at Controller level.

Comment: i fix the problem ,yes i did not see this tutorial, i used script codes on this url. The problem on my controller when i used   "@RequestMapping(value="islemler/konukaydet",method=RequestMethod.POST)" annotation on my controller method it works, no need http://localhost:<port>,   thanks a lot Mr ASquare

Comment: i think that dispatherservlet can not find my controllers method url

Answer (score 0):

In your @RequestMapping you should map full URL At controller method Or add @RequestMapping at controller level Like :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/islemler/") 
public class IslemlerController  {

    @Autowired
    private Dao dao;

    @Autowired
    private Konular _konu;

    @RequestMapping(value = "home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Home(Model model,Dersler dersler)  { 

     model.addAttribute("derslist",dersler);
     return "islemler"; 

    } 


    @ModelAttribute("derslerlistesi")
    public List<Dersler> getdersler ()
    {
        return dao.getAll(Dersler.class);
    }

    @ModelAttribute("konulistesi")
    public List<Konular> getKonular ()
    {
        return dao.getAll(Konular.class);
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="konukaydet",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    private  Konular KonuKaydet (@RequestParam String konu,@RequestParam int dersid)
    {
        _konu.setKonu(konu);
        _konu.setDersid(dersid);
        _konu.setSinavid(1);
        _konu =  dao.save(_konu);
            System.out.println("kaydet e girdi !");
        return _konu;
    }

}
```

Your ajax Call Should be Like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnekle").click(function() {
    var input = {
      "konu": $("#KonuAd").val(),
      "dersid": $("#ddlders").val()
    };
    var inputStr = JSON.stringify(input);
    alert(inputStr);
    $.ajax({
      url: "../islemler/konukaydet",
      type: "POST",
      data: inputStr,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(output) { // callback method for further manipulations
        var str = JSON.stringify(output);
        alert("success ");
        $("#output").text(data);
      },
      error: function(data) { // if error occured
          alert("err");
        $("#error").text(data);
      }
    });

  });
});
```

For your Home Method your URL Is like "../islemler/home"

I hope It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

fix the problem ,

Script code

```
    function madeAjaxCall(){
    var data =  {}
    data["konu"] = $("#konuad").val()
    data["dersid"] = $("#ddlders").val()

 $.ajax({
  type: "post",
//  http://localhost:8080
  url: "/islemler/konukaydet",
  cache: false,    
//  data:'konu=' + $("#konuad").val() + "&dersid;=" + $("#ddlders").val(),
  data:data,
  success: function(response){
   $('#result').html("");
   var obj = JSON.parse(response);
   $('#result').html("First Name:- " + obj.konu +"</br>Last Name:- " + obj.dersid  );
  },
  error: function(){      
   alert('Error while request..');
  }
 });
}
```

and controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="islemler/konukaydet",method=RequestMethod.POST)
private   @ResponseBody  Konular KonuKaydet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{
    _konu.setKonu(request.getParameter("konu"));
    _konu.setDersid(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dersid")));
    _konu.setSinavid(1);
    _konu =  dao.save(_konu);
        System.out.println("kaydet e girdi !");

    return _konu;
}
```

so many thanks ... :)